# AWS boto - Instance Status/Snapshot Status won't update Python While Loop

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

So I am creating a Python script with boto to allow the user to prepare to expand their Linux root volume and partition. During the first part of the script, I would like to have a While loop or something similar to make the script not continue until:

a) the instance has been fully stopped

b) the snapshot has been finished creating.

---

Here are the code snippets for both of these:

Instance:

```
ins_prog = conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=src_ins, filters={"instance-state":"stopped"})
while ins_prog == "[]":
    print src_ins + " is still shutting down..."
    time.sleep(2) 
        if ins_prog != "[]":
        break
```

Snapshot:

```
snap_prog = conn.get_all_snapshots(snapshot_ids=snap_id, filters={"progress":"100"})
while snap_prog == "[]":
    print snap.update
    time.sleep(2) 
        if snap_prog != "[]":
        print "done!"
        break
```

So when calling `conn.get_all_instances` and `conn.get_all_snapshots` they return an empty list if the filters show nothing, which is formatted like `[]`. The problem is the While loop does not even run. It's as if it does not recognize `[]` as the string produced by the `get_all` functions.

If there is an easier way to do this, please let me know I am at a loss right now ):

Thanks!

Edit: Based on garnaat's help here is the follow up issue.

```
snap_prog = conn.get_all_snapshots(snapshot_ids=snap.id)[0]
print snap_prog
print snap_prog.id
print snap_prog.volume_id
print snap_prog.status
print snap_prog.progress
print snap_prog.start_time
print snap_prog.owner_id
print snap_prog.owner_alias
print snap_prog.volume_size
print snap_prog.description
print snap_prog.encrypted
```

Results:

```
Snapshot:snap-xxx
snap-xxx
vol-xxx
pending

2015-02-12T21:55:40.000Z
xxxx
None
50
Created by expandDong.py at 2015-02-12 21:55:39
False
```

Note how `snap_prog.progress` returns null, but `snap_prog.status` stays as 'pending' when being placed in a While loop.

**SOLVED:**

MY colleague and I found out how to get the loop for snapshot working.

```
snap = conn.create_snapshot(src_vol)

while snap.status != 'completed':
    snap.update()
    print snap.status
    time.sleep(5)
        if snap.status == 'completed':
        print snap.id + ' is complete.'
        break
```

`snap.update()` call purely updates the variable `snap` to return the most recent information, where `snap.status` outputs the "pending" | "completed". I also had an issue with `snap.status` not showing the correct status of the snapshot according to the console. Apparently there is a significant lagtime between the Console and the SDK call. I had to wait ~4 minutes for the status to update to "completed" when the snapshot was completed in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I wanted to check the state of a particular instance and wait until that instance reached some state, I would do this:

```
import time    
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2')  # or whatever region you want
instance = conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=['i-12345678'])[0].instances[0]
while instance.state != 'stopped':
    time.sleep(2)
    instance.update()
```

The funny business with the `get_all_instances` call is necessary because that call returns a `Reservation` object which, in turn, has an `instances` attribute that is a list of all matching instances.  So, we are taking the first (and only) `Reservation` in the list and then getting the first (and only) `Instance` inside the reservation.  You should probably but some error checking around that.

The snapshot can be handled in a similar way.

```
snapshot = conn.get_all_snapshots(snapshot_ids=['snap-12345678'])[0]
while snapshot.status != 'completed':
    time.sleep(2)
    snapshot.update()
```

The `update()` method on both objects queries EC2 for the latest state of the object and updates the local object with that state.

Comment: I am lucky I did not try to make my answer boto-specific, would most probably not have been better than yours ;). Nice that you are looking out here on SO for boto-related questions.

Comment: I'm sure you would have done just fine. I really like SO. It's a great place to get information and to provide information. I'm planning a major celebration when I finally hit 10K points 8^)

Comment: You know, I used boto for a project for LHC (CERN)-related simulations in 2008 and a Google Summer of Code project in 2009, and it was really fun :-). And now I just realized that the project evolved tremendously in the past years (version 2.x, yei), and that your AWS times are already behind you (Scopely.. games? Sounds intriguing ;-)). Good luck for hitting the 10K ;-).

Comment: Hi, garnaat! Thank you for the response. I got my while loop working for instance.update(). However, I am having some trouble with snapshot.update().

The following will output just a blank string:

`snapshot.update()`
`snapshot.progress`

The only one that seems to work is `snapshot.status` but inside the while loop it does not update to 'complete' it stays at 'pending' since the snapshots conception.

Comment: I edited my initial question adding all the return options for snapshot.py, also I just figured out who you are. So thanks for all the work on boto (;

Comment: The ``progress`` attribute should be available although I see it is actually a string like ``"100%"`` rather than the ``"100"`` my example assumed.  But you could also poll for ``status``.  I will update the example to do that.  And you are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I will try to answer this generally first. So, you are querying a resource for its state. If a certain state is not met, you want to keep on querying/asking/polling the resource, *until* it is in the state you wish it to be. Obviously this requires you to actually perform the query *within* your loop. That is, in an abstract sense:

```
state = resource.query()
while state != desired_state:
    time.sleep(T)
    state = resource.query()
```

Think about how and why this works, in general.

Now, regarding your code and question, there are some uncertainties you need to figure out yourself. First of all, I am very sure that `conn.get_all_instances()` returns an empty list in your case and not actually the string `'[]'`. That is, your check should be for an **empty list** instead of for a certain string(*). Checking for an empty list in Python is as easy as `not l`:

```
l = give_me_some_list()
if not l:
    print "that list is empty."
```

The other problem in your code is that you expect too much of the language/architecture you are using here. You query a resource and store the result in `ins_prog`. After that, you keep on checking `ins_prog`, as if this would "magically" update via some magic process in the background. No, that is not happening! You need to periodically call `conn.get_all_instances()` in order to get updated information.

(*) This is documented here: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.get_all_instances -- the docs explicitly state **"Return type:    list"**. Not string.

Comment: Hi Jan-Philip Gehrcke, Thanks for the high-level input on my issue. I am by no means a Python coder, or coder in general. The comments on my logic were constructive and I realized where I went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Your question style actually suggested that you might need some help on this level, and I think this is a good example of why inexperienced programmers need not to be frightened to ask on StackOverflow. However, you really should combine both answers here :-), because @garnaat's answer tells you how to use boto in this case.